# Is HEIC/HEIF Supported By UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, ios11, heif

I was under the impression that UIImage would support HEIC/HEIF files introduced in iOS 11. In my testing that does not appear to be the case though. If I do let image = UIImage(named: "test") which points to test.heic then image is nil. If I use an image literal then it crashes the app. Wondering if this is not implemented yet for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Zhao's answer works, it is fairly slow. The below is about 10-20 times faster. It still doesn't work in the simulator for some reason though so keep that in mind.

```
func convert(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else { return nil }
    guard let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, nil) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

This is kind of outlined on page 141 from the slides of a WWDC session but wasn't super clear to me before: https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/511tj33587vdhds/511/511_working_with_heif_and_hevc.pdf

Unfortunately I still haven't been able to figure out a way to use images in the xcassets folder so you'll either have to include the files outside of assets or pull from on the web. If anyone knows a way around this please post.

Comment: I have a HEIC file copied to my documents folder, CGImageSourceCreateWithURL fails on it's URL

Comment: I know this is old, but I cannot get this to work any faster than loading it with UIImage(named:)

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 10.1 (10B61), `UIImage(named: "YourHeifImage")` works just like other assets.

---

Interestingly though, when you want to try this out …and you AirDrop a HEIF pic from your (e.g. iPhone) Photos to your mac, it will get the extension `.HEIC` (all caps). When you then add that image to your Xcode xcassets, Xcode complains about an incorrect extension:

> ….xcassets: warning: Ambiguous Content: The image set "IMG_1791" references a file "IMG_1791.HEIC", but that file **does not have a valid extension**.

If you first change the extension to the lower-case `.heic`, and then add it to xcassets, all is well.

Comment: Thanks @PDK. Don't suppose you've done any performance metrics to see how much slower this is than a regular jpg image?

Comment: Interesting. In response to performance, it was still way slower than jpg images. don't remember how much but was at least an order of magnitude more. They might be using a more efficient method under the hood for xcassets as that didn't work when I had tried this before. Actually just realized I put some benchmarks above already (but obviously dated now)

Answer (score 3):

You can load HEIF via CIImage, then convert to UIImage

```
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage];
```

Comment: Thanks @zhao yang. Just FYI to everyone this doesn't work on the simulator on either mac OS Sierra or High Sierra. I did some test on my 6s as I wanted to see how long loading time was between an image the same pixel size. Here are my results:

jpeg took: 0.039974667 seconds
heif took: 0.464739167 seconds

heif took: 0.279650166 seconds
jpeg took: 0.021772125 seconds

jpeg took: 0.056782417 seconds
heif took: 0.194127875 seconds